# Uploading a file to the teams onedrive from custom teams app tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Im trying to get the tab in my custom teams app to fetch a list of files from a URL, and want to upload one of those files to the corresponding teams onedrive afterwards. I have somewhat been able to do the first part (fetching a list of files) but im completely lost on how to use Graph API or an incoming webhook, or whatever solution available to upload a file to the teams onedrive without having to manually upload it. How do i get my app to upload the file to teams from a URL?

My code as it is right now:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {
      this.setState({
        context: context
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://posts123.free.beeceptor.com")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            files: result.files
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }


  render() {   
    const { error, isLoaded, files } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {files.map(file => (
            <li key={file.id}>
              {file.name} {file.type}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default Tab;
```

I somehow need to pick an item off that list, and then use the graph API or another solution to upload that file to the teams onedrive, how do i do that?

Any help greatly appreciated! On a side note, im completely new to javascript.

Comment: HI @7BitAscii, Yes you can upload file automatically to one-drive using API please go through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online) for your reference.

Comment: @Ravindra-MSFT from what im reading, that is specifically for items that are already on a onedrive or sharepoint. My goal is to upload a new file thats not associated with any microsoft product to the onedrive of my team within MS teams. Is that also possible? or does my file already need to be on a onedrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload files from URLs, Drive using Graph API. You can through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  which provides API for uploading files.